# How could one emulate namespace in C?

Tags: c++, c

In C++ one might use namespace to keep independent groups working in the same code base from inadvertently creating functions with the same name and thus creating a conflict.  My question is, before the idea of namespace comes out, how might one emulate namespace in C.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

By naming things differently, e.g.:

```
void namespace_group_function();
```

[gtk+](http://www.gtk.org/) is a prime example for this conventional style:

```
GtkWidget* gtk_window_new(GtkWindowType type);
```

Comment: It works for isolating independent groups, but it does not support Argument Dependent Lookup and namespace aliasing.

Comment: I really like the fact that the library prefix for classes is CamelCased, while it's underscored for functions. It does keep things look nice and consistent.

Answer (score 7):

Use a common prefix for the names of all of your public symbols, so `foo::bar` becomes `foo_bar`.  tossing a prefix on all of the symbol names is essentially what namespaces do. (and also resolving symbols used without the prefix to declarations that have the prefix, which is pretty helpful)

Answer (score 2):

For symbols not exported you put each module in a separate file.

For exported symbols you generally apply a prefix. Two or three letters are common.